# What does plasmon look like in 3D band structure graph?

Tags: solid-state-physics

Consider metal, and its reciprocal lattice representation with Fermi surface.

What is the correct way to represent a plasmon in this system? M.b. rotating points on the surface? Or 3d membrane-like oscillation of surface? Or what?